# Python selenium загрузка cookies

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

**У меня есть куки вытащенные из другой программы можно ли их подгрузить в Python/selenium? Если да то как?**

{"cookies":[{"creation":{"day_of_month":"22","day_of_week":"1","hour":"8","millisecond":"407","minute":"27","month":"4","second":"8","year":"2019"},"domain":".google.com","expires":{"day_of_month":"20","day_of_week":"4","hour":"8","millisecond":"959","minute":"38","month":"8","second":"19","year":"2020"},"has_expires":"1","httponly":"0","last_access":{"day_of_month":"22","day_of_week":"1","hour":"8","millisecond":"258","minute":"27","month":"4","second":"28","year":"2019"},"name":"SID","path":"/","secure":"0","value":"YwZsDrqtUIbbr_ytVK3W403nQdMj_DbSCrGG_YJpcd3GU98JiwMfABhsouVY6vOwumn3Lg."},{"creation":{"day_of_month":"22","day_of_week":"1","hour":"8","millisecond":"407","minute":"27","month":"4","second":"8","year":"2019"},"domain":".google.com","expires":{"day_of_month":"22","day_of_week":"1","hour":"8","millisecond":"770","minute":"28","month":"4","second":"37","year":"2019"},"name":"SIDCC","path":"/","secure":"0","value":"AN0-TYtaRheNesUAP9wJacTdOACPZXT3ReVry3G35yeCN_86gZdXQqTg4a0kyTs90_5tJHEo"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет [официальная документация selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#cookies), в ней описано, как с помощью selenium можно работать с cookies.

Так же на подобный вопрос отвечали [на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919525/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-a-specific-domain-in-selenium-webdriver-with-python).